# Get the last result from the mysql resultset in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with data as follows.

```
Name      Age
Alex      23
Tom       24
```

Now how do i get the last row only ie. the row containing "Tom" in Mysql Stored Procedure using the select statement and without considering the Name and Age.
Thanks.

Comment: show your effort that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> without considering the Name and Age

That's not possible. There's no "first" or "last" row in a result set as long as you don't add an `ORDER BY a_column` to your query. The result you see is kind of random. You might see the same result over and over again, when you execute the query 1000 times, this might change however when an index gets rewritten or more rows are added to the table and therefore the execution plan for the query changes. It's **random!**

Comment: But i doubt about your definition, as we can execute and modify the query : SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() . what you say

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what you want to tell me with LAST_INSERT_ID(). You know it's **session bound**? Not table bound or whatever you might think?

Answer (score 0):

Add `ORDER BY` and `limit 1` to your `select * from...`

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT TOP 1 name, age FROM table ORDER BY name desc`
or use `ORDER BY` to order it by whatever you want to order your list by. The trick is, to order it descending, instead of ascending.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from table
ORDER BY Name desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Aren't there any mysql built in functions?

Comment: No, there aren't. Explanation in my answer :)

Comment: Nothing native to MySQL, no. You don't have an autoincrementing id either so we have to use Name.

Answer (score 0):

Every idle table should have Auto_increment index named INDEX_NO which use to have highest number, then your table would have items this way

```
INDEX_NO   Name      Age
 1         Alex      23
 2         Tom       24
```

and then you can use this query and i can say that this is fast.

```
SELECT * from table
ORDER BY INDEX_NO desc
LIMIT 1;
```